# Exponential of large negative numbers

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, exponential

How does one compute a number such as np.exp(-28000) on Python? The answer is around 5E-12161. I've been told that due to the double-precision floating point format, I would only be able to calculate a number > 1e-2048

Comment: what's the problem with np.exp(-28000) ?

Comment: I get 0.0 for np.exp(-28000)

Comment: What are you going to do with this number?  Can you arrange your calculations so that you only need to work with the logarithms of the numbers?  -28000 is much easier to work with than exp(-28000).

Comment: I am trying to create a damped sinusoid with a given time array going up to 28000

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Please see my full question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43100725/6943476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the decimal module.

```
Decimal(math.exp(1))**-28000
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I need to figure out how to do this for an array

Comment: @DanielGeorge : I added an approach to make it to work on arrays. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Try [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) for floating-point arithmetic with arbitrary precision

Edit 1:

```
>>> import mpmath as mp 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.matrix((0,0)) 
>>> print(a)
[0.0 0.0]
>>> b = mp.matrix(a.tolist())
>>> c = b.apply(mp.exp)
>>> print(c)
[1.0]
[1.0]
```

Comment: I tried installing that module using pip but it did not show up during compilation. Also, I am trying to find the exponential of an array and I heard mpmath does not do this.

Comment: For mpmath array, array wise operations can be done. Please see the above example

Comment: @arduinolover : This didn't work for numpy arrays and I don't know how to convert the numpy arrays to mp format.

Comment: @arduinolover: Is there an easy way to convert arrays into matrices? Please see my full question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43100725/6943476

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to calculate the "bigexponent" and apply it to the array (along an axis). But, note that the input array has to be of type `int`.

```
# solution courtesy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43084475/2956066
In [97]: def bigexp(x):
    ...:     return Decimal(math.exp(1))**x


In [98]: np.apply_along_axis(bigexp, 1, arr)
```

---

Efficiency (in descending order)

```
# twice faster than applying along axis 0
In [115]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(bigexp, 1, a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 272 µs per loop

In [116]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(bigexp, 0, a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 465 µs per loop
```

Comment: I tried using your method but am getting this error: ValueError: axis must be less than arr.ndim; axis=1, rank=1.
Please see the full question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43100725/6943476