# How can i avoid getting result 0 from exp() for very small float numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, exp

I'm trying to get the exact value from an exponential that gets a very small floating point as input and gives me the result 0.

You can reproduce the problem with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, log, exp, pi

k = np.array([[-746.9292399]])
z = exp(k)
print(z)
```

The result of this will be 0 , for my pc the result of anything smaller than -743.0 will be 0

I have tried using mpmath to solve this as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, log, exp, pi
import mpmath as mp

k = np.array([[-746.9292399]])
z = mp.exp(float(k))
print(z)

det = np.linalg.det([[z,2,3],[2,2,z],[3,6,2]])
print(det)
```

Which is giving a good answer for the exp() , however i will further need to put that result in a numpy array , and extract the determinant from it , which throws an error in the code i attached because numpy doesn't like mpf numbers in its arrays.

Anybody knows how could i get the result from exp() in a way that i can use it with numpy and its functions?

Comment: For reference, mathematically, `exp(-746.9292399)` is ‭4.0997...e-325‬. The minimum value of [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is 4.940656...E-324

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem with `exp` and `log` functions, as the output tends to disappear to zero rather quickly. A good observation is that you typically want `expr(x) - 1` in most scientific computations, and most implementations provide a custom function for that to avoid numerical stability issues. So, if it fits your use case, you should definitely consider `expm1`. Similar considerations also apply to `log`, and hence we have `log1p`, `expm1`, `log1pexp`, `log1mexp` etc. See here for details: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html

Comment: im trying to implement a probability density function for an expectation-maximization algorithm , i have tried your apprach however the final estimations were more accurate before (at the moment im just doing a simple if(x < -743): x = -743 in an attemp to make the program not throw an error) . @alias

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that around `exp(-745)` the value is the smallest that a float can hold.

notice that

```
>>> exp(-744)
1e-323
```

The floating point has moved almost entirely to the right.
I believe that this is the limit of python's float.

Comment: Yes , i was wondering if there is a way to overcome this limit.

Comment: I see. I'm not an expert or anything so I probably am no use in this case, but I hope you'll overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've been working on this for about 30 mins now and I got this

```
import decimal
pow(decimal.Decimal(math.exp(1)),decimal.Decimal(-748.9292399))
```

Also, check this [Exponential of large negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084364/exponential-of-large-negative-numbers)

there is one small issue. I calculated your problem with windows calculator and it gave me this 3.819636355e-325